# update the sales table and reduce the quantity from product table in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-3

Hi friends im new to codeignitter,

my problem is i have a page to insert the selling item,

**example:** when a user sells an item he will insert the item details to the form and there is a button in form to update.

What I want to know is, when the user user click that button I must reduce the quantity from `product` table and insert the details to `sales` table.

My table details are below:

## product table:

`pid` , `pname`, `description`, `qty` , `price`

## sales table:

`sid`, `date`, `pname`, `qty`, `price`

Please help me with this. Do I have to make any *foreign key relationship*? If yes, please tell me how to.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: can you give me sql code samples